# How to validate query string parameters in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm wondering, how can I validate query string parameters in PlayFramework 2.x.
Suppose I have pretty common shift, limit (DROP, LIMIT) parameters for sequences, and I have
a route like this:

```
# http://example.com/users?shift=0&limit=20 - take first 20 users
GET    /users         Users.list(shift: Int ?= 0, limit: Int ?= 20)
```

I want to keep my shift and limit in correct bounds for me, e.g limit from 1 to 60, and if user tries to set limit like 23979 it should be reduced to 60. 
Filters does not work for this, cause they fire after router.

Comment: Just validate it at beginning of your action, you can create simple method which will validate if param is numeric and if it fits required range, so you can also catch cases when user will insert some string value there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do like biesor's comment that you can just validate at the beginning of your action. If that is not possible, kfer38's answer works as well. I'd like to throw another answer out, and that is using the Global object. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal

The advantage of a global object over a redirect is that it is done instantly and **reconfigures the router**, rather than a redirect which adds milliseconds to your run time. Since doing things before the router touches them seems to be a concern, I offer this solution.

Something like this would work:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    // string matching here to get the values
    // rewrite values to what you want
    super.onRouteRequest(request.copy(path = newPath))
  }
}
```

I use this to remove "/" at the end of a route, for example, rather than redirect, which is really inefficient. I also do this to avoid having to write twice as many routes just to match ending "/".

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the constraints in the controller `Users.list(shift: Int, limit: Int)`. Then instead of throwing an exception, you can Redirect with your custom values. Ex. `if (limit > 60) Redirect(routes.controllers.Users.list(shift, 60))`

Answer (score 0):

[Michael's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821273/michael-dotson) approach works well for this, but there also a few interesting things.
If I filter query params overriding `onRouteRequest` it filters arguments passed to an action function, but not query string arguments in request object:

```scala
def users(shift: Int, limit: Int) = Action { req =>
  Logger.debug("shift: " + shift)
  Logger.debug("shiftQS: " + req.getQueryString("shift"))
```

If we request `/users?shift=-2` our shift will be filtered and shiftQS not! But situation seems to be different if you use only `Filter`, it can filter query string parameters but not your arguments. So, to filter query string too you should add Play's `Filter`. My final implementation contains something like this:

```scala
// Write your filter and mix it to Global
object SeqFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(next: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(req: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], SimpleResult] = {
      next(doFilter(req))
    }
  }

  def doFilter(req: RequestHeader): RequestHeader = {
    if (/* queryString contains invalid parameters */) {
      val qs = /* You filtered queryString */
      req.copy(queryString = qs)
    } else {
      req
    }
  }
}

// Alson use your filter in onRouteRequest in Global object
override def onRouteRequest(req: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  super.onRouteRequest(SeqFilter.doFilter(req))
}
```